# IOS In App Purchase - How can we give the user access to ALL In App Purchase content once they buy ANY In App Purchase item?

Tags: ios

I have a problem, I have one app with 8 In App Purchases, there is one in app purchase for each one of 8 different "categories". Once the user click on anyone of this and buy it we would like the user to GET ACCESS to ALL of the 8 different categories not only the one that they buy.

It is a game with 8 different groups of questions. Like 8 different game modes depending on who you play with. In example "Friends" "Family" "A couple".

When user makes an In-App purchase, I want him to get access to the questions of all 8 categories!

What do we need to do to make it possible?

Comment: Why do you have 8 then. Confusing for you and the users...

Comment: Its because there is 8 different kinds of questions that shall pop up in each category... this is the game its free with in app purchase...

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/which-one-us-fun-social-free/id673679918?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

You have code which controls what happens when the purchase is completed so you can just action all of the handlers for all groups without checking which group it is. Just check that the purchase was valid.

Comment: Can you tell me more how to do it? Or share code? Im a newbie :)

Comment: Share your code for how you are currently handling the valid transaction(s).

Comment: 1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
//
//  InAppPurchaseManager.h
//  FS2Easy2011FTC
//
//  Created by Shahriar Kabir on 1/6/11.
//  Copyright 2011 TopOfStack Software. All rights reserved.
//

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import "SKProduct+LocalizedPrice.h"
#import "PurchasDoneSuccess.h"
#import "LoaderAlertView.h"
 
typedef enum
{
    Product_Dating,
    Product_Familj,
    Product_Forefest,
    Product_Par,
    Product_ParmidDag,
    Product_Slakt,
    Product_Tjejkvall,
    Product_Vanner

Comment: }QuestionsUnlockerProduct;
 
#define kInAppProductId_Dating     @"product.who.dating"
#define kInAppProductId_Familj     @"product.who.familj"
#define kInAppProductId_Forefest     @"product.who.forefest"
#define kInAppProductId_Par     @"product.who.par"
#define kInAppProductId_ParmidDag     @"product.who.pramiddag"
#define kInAppProductId_Slakt     @"product.who.slakt"
#define kInAppProductId_Tjejkvall     @"product.who.tjejkvall"
#define kInAppProductId_Vanner     @"product.who.vanner"

Comment: 8-O please edit the question to add the code and format it so it's readable (and delete the above comments as they aren't readable) - thanks

Comment: It's the content of `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` that is interesting, or, if you're validating the receipt, the result of the validation.